# How to send a json parameter to postgresql function since PHP with pg_prepare

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I tried to send a json object to an postgresql function with this way: 
PHP CODE:

```
$result = $this->con->execute("select fn_addRemission($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, 
                                     $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54::json, $55::json, $56::json, $57::json, $58::json, $59, $60)",
                                     array($sell->getDate(), $sell->getDocumentType(), $sell->getSerial(), $sell->getFolio(), $sell->getCustomer(), $sell->getDeliveryDate(), $sell->getDueDate(), 
                                           $sell->getBadge(), $sell->getConsumerCenter(), $sell->getSeller(), $sell->getCommission(), $sell->getNotes(), $sell->getDeliveryMan(), $sell->getCarrier(), $sell->getSendTo(),
                                           $sell->getNumberGuide(), $sell->getUsername(), $sell->getChangeType(), $sell->getSubtotal(), $sell->getDiscount(), $sell->getTaxes(), $sell->getImporting(), 
                                           $sell->getCashSession(), $sell->getPersons(), $sell->getPayWay(), $sell->getTable(), $sell->getAdditionalImport(), $sell->getPolicy(), $sell->getManagerStatus(), 
                                           $sell->getDeliveryStatus(), $sell->getBillingStatus(), $sell->getFinancialStatus(), $sell->getAgent(), $sell->getCashBox(), $sell->getAudited(), $sell->getTabulated(), 
                                           $sell->getCharSerie(), $cashMovement->getCategory(), $cashMovement->getPolicy(), $cashMovement->getAudited(), $cashMovement->getAccounted(), $cashMovement->getEffective(), 
                                           $cashMovement->getCard(), $cashMovement->getCheck(), $cashMovement->getDeposit(), $cashMovement->getTicket(), $cashMovement->getReference(), $cashMovement->getChangeType(), 
                                           $cashMovement->getNotes(), $cashMovement->getDocument(), $cashMovement->getBadge(), $cashMovement->getSesion(), $cashMovement->getSerie(), $cashMovement->getDate(),
                                           is_null($cardDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($cardDetail), is_null($checkDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($checkDetail),
                                           is_null($depositDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($depositDetail), is_null($ticketDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($ticketDetail),
                                           is_null($sellDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($sellDetail),
                                           $storageExits, $productionMethod));
```

First I check if a json object is null, if is true I send a empty json object, in contrary case I send my json object parameter

```
function execute($query, $params = null){
    $result = null;
    try {
        if ($params == null || is_null($params)) {
            $result = pg_query($this->con, $query) or die(json_encode(["type" => "Error", "message" => "Error al ejecutar la sentencia SQL COD. 03 " . pg_last_error() . " sentencia SQL: " . $query]));
        } else {
            $result = pg_prepare($this->con, "statement", $query) or die (json_encode(["type" => "Error", "message" => "Error al ejecutar la sentencia SQL COD. 03 " . pg_last_error() . " sentencia SQL: " . $query]));
            $result = pg_execute($this->con, "statement", $params) or die(json_encode(["type" => "Error", "message" => "Error al ejecutar la sentencia SQL COD. 03 " . pg_last_error() . " sentencia SQL: " . $query]));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception(json_encode(["type" => "Error", "message" => "Error al ejecutar la sentencia SQL COD. 03 " . pg_last_error() . " sentencia SQL: " . $query]));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and this is my single postgresql function I'm just trying first to send correctly my params the function hasn't anything logic

```
create or replace function fn_addRemission(sellDate date, sellDocument int, sellSerie int, sellFolio varchar, sellCustomer int, sellDateDelivery date, sellDueDate date,
  sellBadge int, sellConsumerCenter int, sellSeller int, sellCommission numeric(14, 2), sellNotes varchar(250), sellDealer int, sellCarrier int, sellSendTo varchar(200),
  sellNumberGuide varchar(18), sellUserName varchar(70), sellChangeType NUMERIC(14, 2), sellSubTotal NUMERIC(14, 2), sellDiscount NUMERIC(14, 2), sellTaxes NUMERIC(14, 2),
  sellImporting NUMERIC(14, 2), sellCashBoxSession int,  sellPersons int, sellPayWay varchar(30), sellTable int, sellAdditionalImport NUMERIC(14, 2),
  sellPolicy int, sellManagerStatus int, sellDeliveryStatus int, sellBillingStatus int, sellFinancialStatus int, sellAgent int, sellCashBox int,  sellAudited char, sellTabuled char,
  sellCharSerie VARCHAR(5),
  cashBoxCategory int, cashBoxPolicy int, cashBoxAudited char, cashBoxTabuled char, cashBoxCash numeric(14, 2), cashBoxCard NUMERIC(14, 2),
  cashBoxChecks NUMERIC(14, 2), cashBoxDeposits NUMERIC(14, 2), cashBoxTickets NUMERIC(14, 2), cashBoxReference VARCHAR(15), cashBoxChangeType NUMERIC(14, 2), cashBoxNotes VARCHAR(250),
  cashBoxDocument int, cashBoxBadge int, cashBoxSession int, cashBoxSerie VARCHAR(5), cashBoxDate date,
  cardDetails json, checkDetails json, depositDetails json, ticketDetails json, sellDetails json, storageExits char, productionMethod varchar(30))
  returns CHAR
  AS
  $$
  begin
    raise NOTICE 'ARRAY: %', checkDetails;
    return 'S';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
      return 'E';
  end;
  $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I check all data types for all parameters and are correctly the data type

**EDIT::: I find the way to send my params to postgresql function doing following:**

First I quit my conditionals from the array params and create a vars with the json values, like this:

```
        $jsonCardDetail = is_null($cardDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($cardDetail);
        $jsonCheckDetail = is_null($checkDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($cardDetail);
        $jsonDepositDetail = is_null($depositDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($depositDetail);
        $jsonTicketDetail = is_null($ticketDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($ticketDetail);
        $jsonSellDetail = is_null($sellDetail) ? '{}' : json_encode($sellDetail);
```

When I test the postgres function directly from a postgres query requires the reserved word ::json, but in PHP doesn't  necessary,  only need to parse a associative array to json with json_encode.

Some admin can close my question please?